# How does Chebyshev's inequality imply $P(X ≥ k) ≤ 1/(σk)^2$?

Tags: inequality

I am aware that Chebyshev's inequality $P(X ≥ kσ) ≤ 1/k^2$ can also be written as $P(X ≥ k) ≤ 1/(σk)^2$, but I do not understand the math to convert between these forms. Could someone explain/point me towards an explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second form of the inequality is wrong.  The initial form of [Chebychev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) (for a random variable $X$ with zero mean) is:

$$\mathbb{P}(|X| \geqslant k \sigma) \leqslant \frac{1}{k^2}.$$

Letting $k = k_* / \sigma$ and substituting into this initial form gives the alternative form:

$$\mathbb{P}(|X| \geqslant k_*) \leqslant \frac{\sigma^2}{k_*^2}.$$